# "No matter how" vs However

Tags: meaning, difference, usage

What is the difference between the meaning and usage of "However"and "No matter how" in these sentences:
**"However well you speak English, you must remember you can improve"**
and
**"No matter how well you speak English, you must remember you can improve."**

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a matter of usage.  I live on the eastern side of the large salty pond known as the Atlantic ocean and I would use 'However....'.  But I think if you live on the other side then the 'No matter what ...' phrase is more common.

Comment: I can't say I was aware of this AmE/BrE usage split before reading your answer here, but these [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=However+well%2CNo+matter+how+well&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHowever%20well%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNo%20matter%20how%20well%3B%2Cc0) and [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=However+well%2CNo+matter+how+well&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHowever%20well%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNo%20matter%20how%20well%3B%2Cc0) corpus NGrams support you,